# hey im getting segmentation fault in below code for rat in a maze problem

Tags: c++, recursion, segmentation-fault, backtracking, maze

the standard rat in maze problem is given a binary grid if grid[i][j]==0 path blocked rat is in 0,0 find all ways to reach n-1,n-1 cell. I have put all the constraints I guess.

```
  class Solution{
    public:
    // vector<string>ans;
    // vector<pair<int,int>>dir={{0,1},{0,-1},{-1,0},{1,0}};
    // vector<string>move={"R","L","U","D"};
    void dfs(int i,int j,vector<vector<int>>&m,string 
    curr,vector<vector<int>>&visited,vector<pair<int,int>>dir,vector<string>move,vector<string>&ans){
            if(i==m.size()-1 and j==m.size()-1){
                ans.push_back(curr);
                return;
            }


    for(int z=0;z<dir.size();z++ ){
        int nx=i+dir[z].first;
        int ny=j+dir[z].second;
        if(visited[nx][ny]==0 and m[nx][ny]==1 and nx>=0 and nx<m.size() and ny>=0 and 
        ny<m.size() ){
             visited[nx][ny]=1;
             dfs(nx,ny,m,curr+move[z],visited,dir,move,ans);
             visited[nx][ny]=0;
        }    
    }
    
}
vector<string> findPath(vector<vector<int>> &m, int n) {
 vector<vector<int>>visited(m.size(),vector<int>(n,0));
 string curr="";
 vector<string>ans;
 vector<pair<int,int>>dir={{0,1},{0,-1},{-1,0},{1,0}};
 vector<string>move={"R","L","U","D"};
 dfs(0,0,m,curr,visited,dir,move,ans);
 return ans;   
}
```

};

Comment: This won't compile and link as-is (no includes; no `main`), and we have no input data populating `m` for `findPath`, so you still have some work to do for a proper [mcve]. Personally I'd start by fixing the plethora of "signed vs. unsigned integer comparison warnings you would be getting if you turned up your warning levels, and change your critical vector `operator[]` uses (basically all of them) to use `.at()` instead, which range-checks and throws an exception on erroneous indexing.

Answer (score 3):

Change

```
if (visited[nx][ny]==0 and m[nx][ny]==1 and 
    nx>=0 and nx<m.size() and ny>=0 and ny<m.size()) {
```

to

```
if (nx>=0 and nx<m.size() and ny>=0 and ny<m.size() and 
    visited[nx][ny]==0 and m[nx][ny]==1) {
```

You should only check `visited` and `m` **after** you have checked that `nx` and `ny` are in bounds. The order of the two sides of an `and` expression matters.

Comment: This is known as [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Comment: tnx yes it worked

Answer (score 1):

`visited[nx][ny] == 0` is out-of-bounds. `m[nx][ny] == 1` is out-of-bounds too.